# Hadoop log file analysis

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to create a java app. that can be deployed on Hadoop which purpose is below:

- I have lot of larger log files from various servers (Tuxedo logs, Websphere logs and IIS logs)
- I want to analyze these large files to generate as a report which states that from Tux, this many of errors, From Websphere this many are errors/warnings etc

So I need assistance at this point in time with my limited Hadoop knowledge

- Most of the map reduce algo. works on with same type of files not in my case where log files are from various sources (Tux, Websphere, IIS etc)
- How do I design my map() and reduce() functions in this case
- How do I store the log reports (For ex: from Tux the error/warnings, from Websphere the error/warning/info) combination etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache flume is the answer for this scenario